# Angular FormControl CheckBox selection marks every sibling

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, checkbox, form-control

StackBlitz: http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jul7bv

I am having trouble with Angular FromControl, that are being created dynamicly based od passed data.

My list displays Groups and Subgroups of specific Data, everything works almost perfectly fine, but whenever I check subgroup, every of its sibling is being marked and i am unable to come up whats wrong.

Thats my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let chapter of checkboxControlLabels; let i = index;">
      <div class="input-checkbox-subgroup-list__checkbox">
        <div class="input-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" [attr.id]="chapter.id + '_checkboxControl_' + i"
            [formControl]="getChapterControl(i)" />
          <label [attr.for]="chapter.id + '_checkboxControl_'+ i">{{ chapter.title }} </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-checkbox-subgroup-list__checkbox" *ngFor="let chart of chapter.charts; let x = index;">
        <div class="input-checkbox chart">
          <input type="checkbox" [attr.id]="chart.title + '_checkboxControl_' + x" [formControl]="getChartControl(i, x)" />
          <label [attr.for]="chart.title + '_checkboxControl_' + x">{{ chart.heading }} </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is how I am mapping specific FormControl :

```
  getChartControl(chapterIndex: string, chartIndex: number) {
    return this.data.controls[chapterIndex].get('charts').controls[chartIndex];
  }
```

As you can see on below image when I check subgroup, there is 11 selected and I have no idea how thats possible.

More intresting thing is that this doesnt apply to groups... So if I would check First group there would be only one selected...

This is FormGroupModel that I am using later on:

```
this.chapterChartsData.forEach(chapters => {
      dataForm.push(new FormGroup({
        chapter: new FormControl(false),
        charts: new FormArray(Array(chapters.charts.length).fill(new FormControl(false)))
      }))
    });
```

Comment: Can you create stackbliz?

Comment: Also share the initialisation of formgroup/formarray such as this.data.

Comment: stackblitz would pretty hard to create because im using lots of components to this. Initial FormGroup that I am using is added.

Comment: @Krzysztof  Check this video to https://youtu.be/acDFvTPMKxM

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jul7bv 

I have created and repeated problem that im having, please have a look. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently problem was with populating list of form controls like that :

```
charts: new FormArray(Array(chapters.charts.length).fill(new FormControl(false)))
```